# Prime numbers are related by $q=2p+1$

Tags: number-theory

Let primes $p$ and $q$ be related by $q=2p+1$.  Prove that there is a positive multiple of $q$ for which the sum of its digits does not exceed $3$.

**My work so far:**

$p,q -$ primes and $q=2p+1 \Rightarrow \exists n,k \in \mathbb N: n=qk$ and $S(n) \le 3$

$p=2 \Rightarrow q=5 \Rightarrow 5|10=n; S(10)=1 \le3$.

$p=3 \Rightarrow q=7 \Rightarrow 7|21=n; S(21)=3 \le3$.

$p=5 \Rightarrow q=11 \Rightarrow 1|11=n; S(11)=2 \le3$.

$p=7 \Rightarrow q=15=5 \cdot3 $.

$p=11 \Rightarrow q=23 \Rightarrow 23|n; S(n) \le3$.

Comment: What does "it has the sum of numbers not exceeding $3$" mean?

Comment: @mjqxxxx Sum of digits.

Comment: Try to find one for $p=29, q=59$. I'm having a hard time.

Comment: @MXYMXY $339\cdot 59=20001$

Comment: Here $x^k = xxx\dots \ k \ \text{times}$. The possible forms of a multiple of $q$ are
$$10^i, 10^i10^j, 20^i, 10^i10^j10^k, 20^i10^j, 10^i20^j, 30^i$$

Comment: @BanachTarski if you suppose $q\neq2,5$ then you can discard the first, third and last case, in the second fifth and sixth case wlog $j=0$, in the fourth $k=0$, simply because if $m q$ is divisible by $10$ with $q$ prime, then either $m$ is divisible by $10$, or $q=2,5$

Comment: If we can find a number $m$ such that $10^m\equiv p\ (\ mod\ q\ )$, we are done because we then have $2\times 10^m+1\equiv 2p+1\equiv 0\ (\ mod\ q\ )$

Comment: The cases where $q \neq 19, 7, 23 \pmod {40}$ are quite easy.

Comment: @Peter it seems like not all $p\equiv 10^m$ (mod $q$) are solvable. Let $g$ be a primitive root of (mod $q$), then $g^a\equiv 10$, $g^b\equiv p$ (mod $q$). We need to find $am\equiv b$ (mod $2p$) since $2p$ is the order of $g$, then it is only solvable if $b\equiv 0$ (mod $GCD(a,2p)$), which is not guaranteed. An example of this is $p=5$, $q=11$. There is no multiple of $q$ that is in the form of $2*10^m+1$. This is also one of the difficulties of this problem, $kq$ can have 3 cases: $2*10^m+1$, $10^n+10^m+1$ or $10^m+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(ALMOST an answer)** In order for $S(kq)\leq3$, $kq$ must be in one of the following forms:

(1): $$kq=2*10^n+1$$
(2): $$kq=10^n+1$$
(3): $$kq=10^n+10^m+1$$, where $n\neq m$

We will look into the cases one by one and show that there must exist some $n$ or $n,m$ that satisfy at least one of the above cases, following @Peter 's direction.

---

**Case (1):**

$2*10^n+1\equiv2p+1$ (mod $q$)
$10^n\equiv p$

Now let $g$ be a primitive root for mod $q$, such that $g^a\equiv10$ and $g^b\equiv p$ (mod $q$), where $1\leq a,b\leq 2p$

Then the question reduces to whether $g^{an}=g^b$ (mod q) is solvable or not. And since the primitive root has order $2p$,

$an\equiv b$ (mod $2p$)

Is only solvable iff
$b\equiv 0$ (mod $GCD(a,2p)$)

So if $a,2p$ are coprime, there must be an integer $0\geq n\geq 2p$ that satisfies $kq=2*10^n+1$

---

**Case (2):**

If the above case fails, that means $b\not\equiv 0$ (mod $GCD(a,2p)$)

Then $a$ and $2p$ must not be coprime, since $p$ is a prime, $a=p$ or $a=2$.

$2p\equiv -1\equiv 10^n$ (mod $q$)

Let $g^c\equiv 2$ (mod $q$), $1\leq c\leq 2p$

We know,
$g^p\equiv g^{b+c}\equiv -1$

Because $(g^p)^2\equiv 1$ (mod $q$) but $p\not\equiv 0$ (mod $2p$)

If $g^p\equiv g^{an}$ is solvable

Then,
$p\equiv an$ (mod $2p$) has a solution for $n$, and it has solution iff

$p\equiv 0$ (mod $GCD(a,2p)$)

---

Sub-case: $a=p$,

$p\equiv 0$ (mod $a=p$) is trivial

So there must be solution for $n$ if $a=p$

---

Sub-case: $a=2$,  there must be solution for $n$ if $b,c$ have the same parity.

In fact, $1 \leq b,c \leq 2p$ implies that $2\leq b+c\leq 4p$,

so $b+c=p$ or $b+c=3p$,

because if $b+c=2p$ or $4p$, it would contradict that $g^{b+c}\equiv -1$ (mod $q$)

So $b+c\equiv 1$ (mod $a=2$), for the case that $a=2$, there will be no solution in the form of (1) or (2).

---

**Case (3):**

$kq=10^n+10^m+1$

$2p\equiv 10^n+10^m$ (mod $q$)

$g^{b+c}\equiv -1\equiv g^{2n}+g^{2m}$

I cant figure how to show that this type of equation has solution $n,m$. If you can prove that there exist solutions, then we have covered all possible cases.

(Side note: it can be shown that if $a=p$, then there must be no solution in the form $10^n+10^m+1$ since

$g^{pm}+g^{pn}+1\not\equiv 0$ (mod $q$) since $g^{pm},g^{pn}\equiv \pm 1$)