# Is it possible to show that there are integer solutions $n,m$ for $10^m+10^n+1\equiv 0$ (mod $q$) for a prime $q$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I came across to this question: [Prime numbers are related by $q=2p+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698878/prime-numbers-are-related-by-q-2p1)

I have almost figured out the answer, but got stuck at the final step to show the following:

For prime numbers $p,q$ that $q=2p+1$, there exists integers $k$ such that the sum of digit of $kq$ is less than or equal to $3$.

I need to show that if $g$ is a primitive root for mod $q$, and $g^2\equiv 10$ (mod $q$), then there must be some integer $1\leq n,m\leq 2p$ such that $g^{2n}+g^{2m}+1\equiv 0$ (mod $q$)

Comment: Yes, for the title question. Just take a prime divisor of $10^m+10^n+1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde sorry if the title was confusing, I want to know for any prime $q$ in the form of $2p+1$, where $p$ is another prime, if there must exists integers $n,m$ such that $10^n+10^m+1\equiv 0 (\mod q)$. I only care about the existence but not about how to find them.

Comment: You might want to take a look at $q=11$.

Comment: @MikeBennett I know, that's also what I have shown in the link in the post. If $10=g^p(\mod q)$ for primitive root $g$, then  $kq=10^n+1$. But here I set $10=g^2$ (mod $q$)